# AWS Amplify integration with Vite React TypeScript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, vite

I'm trying to integrate AWS Amplify into my Vite TypeScript React application. When I try to import the `aws-exports.js` file generated by the `amplify init` command:

**main.tsx**

```js
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
```

**aws-exports.js**

```js
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
  aws_project_region: "eu-central-1",
};

module.exports = { default: awsmobile };
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/aws-exports.js' does
> not provide an export named 'default'

I tried multiple hackish solutions online and [adding a declaration file](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular/#strictly-typing-aws-exports) and converting the auto-generated `aws-exports` to a ts file:

**aws-exports.d.ts**

```js
declare const awsmobile: Record<string, any>
export default awsmobile;
```

but still, it doesn't work as I see that there is no TypeScript support for it yet. I tried to convert it to ts-compliant code but as the warning mentioned, it shouldn't be edited. Is there a proper way to solve this issue?

Comment: Your `aws-exports.js` file doesn't look right to me - you should have `export default awsmobile;` and not what you have there. Can you delete it please and re-run `amplify pull`? If you still get the above contents, can you please run `npm update @aws-amplify/cli` and try again? (with the `-g` argument if installed globally)

Comment: Delete your amplify folder and pull it again. You can pull a specific environment by going to the AWS Amplify console, backend, your env, and then copy the code at the bottom.